# Umbraco 301 redirect with a twist

Tags: umbraco

I have installed uComponents and successfully use the umbraco301MovedPermanently property on a page to redirect the old urls to the shiny new umbraco installation.

My problem is, it does not work with the umbracoUrlName property. i.e. it redirects to the umbraco Link url, but not to the umbracoUrlName I have also specified.

Anyone knows a trick how to do this?

Thanks
Themos

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

- forcing a publish of the page by right-clicking on the page in question and "Publish";
- right-clicking the Content tree and doing "Republish entire site"?

Umbraco's URL handler uses an XPath handler to resolve URLs and forcing the file-based XML cache to update (by publishing the individual page, or forcing the entire site's XML cache to repopulate, using the respective methods above) may force the correct URL specified in your umbracoUrlName property to be picked up and used accordingly.